# How to change cells spacing in an swt Table

Tags: java, swt, jface, spacing

Please I'm trying to change the SWT table cell spacing between two TableItems but I haven't found a suitable way to do it.

So is it possible to change it; and how to do it?

Comment: Do you want to change the spacing between rows or columns (or both)?

Comment: I'm asking about rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the row height using an `SWT.MeasureItem` listener:

```
table.addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, new Listener()
 {
   public void handleEvent(Event event)
   {
     event.height = row height (pixels)
   }
 });
```

Comment: +1 Was just about to post the same... There is a complete example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/EnlargeTableCell.htm) as well.

Comment: Thanks greg but this increases the row size' what I want is the between cell spacing and thus this wouldn't work

Comment: I don't really follow. To do any more you have to draw everything yourself using `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` (JFace) or SWT.MeasureItem, SWT.EraseItem and SWT.PaintItem (SWT).